# Split data element based on delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database called `Property` with a table called `Location`.  The data looks like this:

```
RecordID     Location
-----------------------
    1        1/21/s15
    2        8/1/21c59
    3        1//
    4        9//72
```

I have a script that reads records from the table and inserts them into a second table called `ExpandedLocation`.

This is the code of my script:

```
INSERT INTO [Property].[dbo].[ExpandedLocation] (LocationA, LocationB, LocationC)
    SELECT 
        dbo.fnBuildABC(Location, 1), 
        dbo.fnBuildABC(Location, 2), 
        dbo.fnBuildABC(Location, 3)
    FROM 
        [Property].[dbo].[Location]
```

This code should call the function `fnBuildABC` and pass it 2 parameters, `Location` and a number. The function should take in the parameters and split the first parameter on the slash and return either the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd portion of the passed string.

So, for example, on the first read of the Location table, I pick up the value 1/21/s15.

The function should return the following:

```
Parameter Value    Returned Value
---------------------------------
Location, 1            1
Location, 2            21
Location, 3            s15
```

On the second read of the `Location` table, I pick up the value `8/1/21c59`. The function should return the following:

```
Parameter Value      Returned Value
-----------------------------------
Location, 1             8
Location, 2             1
Location, 3             21c59
```

I'm at a loss as to how to split the passed string in the function without actually inspecting each character of the string one at a time.

Any suggestions on how to start this process would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want a function to return only s single value, that means you are doing the same work 3 times once for each column, why not simply split the values in one go and insert into the target columns.

Comment: create or alter function BuildABC(@location varchar (10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build a function that splits your string and returns 3 columns as a table.

With just 3 columns you can comfortably do that with a combination of SQL Server's string functions.

An example of a function would be:

```
create or alter function fnBuildABC(@location varchar(10))
returns table 
as
return
select 
    Left(location, p1.v - 1) A,
    Substring(location, p1.v + 1, p2.v - p1.v - 1) B,
    Stuff(location, 1, p2.v, '') C
from (select location = @Location)l
cross apply(values(CharIndex('/', location)))p1(v)
cross apply(values(CharIndex('/', location, p1.v + 1)))p2(v);
```

And then you can use it with your `Location` table:

```
insert into Property.dbo.ExpandedLocation (LocationA, LocationB, LocationC)
select A, B, C
from dbo.Location
cross apply fnBuildABC(Location);
```

Example [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mEpXqCbJ)

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a built in [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function that you can probably use. It returns a table of split values.

```
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('1/21/s15', '/')
```

Example output:

| Value |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 21 |
| s15 |

Answer (score 0):

You may try using XML method as the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnBuildABC( @loc VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @splitted TABLE
(
  [Parameter Value] INT,
  [Returned Value] VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @xml xml;
SET @xml = N'<root><p>' + replace(@loc, '/','</p><p>') + '</p></root>';

INSERT INTO @splitted
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY l_pos) AS pos,
  l_pos.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS val
  FROM
  @xml.nodes('//root/p') AS Portions(l_pos)

RETURN;
END;
```

To get all portions of a location call the function as the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Location: ', [Parameter Value]) AS [Parameter Value], [Returned Value]
FROM
(
  SELECT L.RecordID, P.* FROM ExpandedLocation L
  OUTER APPLY
  fnBuildABC(Location) P
) T
WHERE RecordID = 1;
```

To get specific portions, i.e. 1 & 2:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Location: ', [Parameter Value]) AS [Parameter Value], [Returned Value]
FROM
(
  SELECT L.RecordID, P.* FROM ExpandedLocation L
  OUTER APPLY
  fnBuildABC(Location) P
) T
WHERE RecordID = 1 AND [Parameter Value] IN (1,2);
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/um5cyWWJ).